# Does order of UFW rules matter?

Tags: firewall, spam, ufw

When I first initialized my ufw, I did

```
ufw default allow outgoing
ufw default deny incoming
ufw allow 80/tcp
ufw allow 22/tcp
```

Over the last week or so, I've been going through my access logs and banning IPs that are making malicious requests on my server

I'd do so using

```
ufw deny from <ip>
```

---

Here's my `ufw status verbose`

> All the IPs pasted here are from sick-filth spammers; take no pity on them

```
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), disabled (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere                   DENY IN     125.39.22.154
Anywhere                   DENY IN     222.124.200.250
Anywhere                   DENY IN     101.60.178.197
Anywhere                   DENY IN     115.184.115.200
Anywhere                   DENY IN     93.174.93.129
... more ips ...
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

---

**Question**

What I'm noticing is that the `ALLOW` actions are before the `DENY` actions.

Does the order of the rules actually matter? Or can I rest peacefully knowing that my IP block has worked?

Side question: Is there a more effective way to handle spammy requests than manually `grep`ing access/error logs for malicious requests and blocking those IPs from making future requests?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does the order of the rules actually matter?

Yes it does. Denies should be first *in this case* since they are more specific (more specific rules should go first).  [Example](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW#Advanced_Example)

> Is there a more effective way to handle spammy requests than manually

fail2ban can scan logs, and add IPs to many types of filtering systems that match defined patterns.

Comment: The example page you reference says "you must put the specific rules first".  So if I wanted to deny from all except for a few trusted IP addresses, I would actually put the allow rules first, correct?

Comment: Yes, in that case you want your allow rules first.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct ufw to insert rules at a given position:

```
ufw insert 1 deny from <ip> to any
```

This inserts the deny rule in first position instead of last.